# How to convert damaged Cyrillic to normal

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have files on the server. Originally their names are readable and users put their files (names contain Cyrillic symbols) into the server and I get their files from my app. The problem is when I get this files from the server their names differ from their original names. Something like that "Ìóõòîð...", but original names doesn't contain such symbols (only абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьъэюя). I don't know how do they upload files (they have ftp access), but certainly know that their names are "good" before upload and "damaged" after, on the server. Even filezilla shows their names corrupted.

I need help to restore damaged names. I use Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    String s = "Ìóõòîð";
    final byte[] cp1252s = s.getBytes("Cp1252");
    final String s1 = new String(cp1252s, "Cp1251");
    System.out.println(s1);
```

Prints: Мухтор

Comment: Thank you, it works. But there is another question.. For example if the name isnt in Cp1252 charset (win, any other) will be there errors in converting? And if yes then how do I detect current string charset?

Comment: You can use this for encoding detection: http://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/